# Unexpected Guid change during a Linq request

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to understand the following snippet:

```
class TestNewGuid
{
    public Guid RequestId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    // any other fields
}

[Fact]
public void Test()
{
    var toInitAnEnumerable = new int[] {1};
    var requests = toInitAnEnumerable
        .Select(a => new TestNewGuid());

    var requestIds = requests
        .Select(a => a.RequestId)
        .ToHashSet(); // this calls the TestNewGuid's constructor
    
    Assert.Equal(requestIds.First(), requests.First().RequestId); // Always fails
}
```

I'm surprise by the fact that the RequestId changes.

I know that `ToHashSet()` will create a copy, but because I have the `.Select(a => a.RequestId)` before, I don't understand why it creates a copy of `TestNewGuid` and not of the `Guid`.

Any idea?

Comment: You have not shown us the definition of `removeSome`.

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo, fixed it, I renamed it without changing it everywhere

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Are you sure the constructor of `TestNewGuid` is only called once?

Comment: In debugging, the ToHashSet() triggers TestNewGuid's constructor once more.

Comment: oooh, this is a good way to indicate why visual studio will tend to warn you about "possible multiple enumerations"!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Select` is not evaluated when you call it, it is what is known as "deferred execution" - which is to say it only runs when a method which will materialize the enumerable is executed. There are 2 such methods in your code; `First()` in the assertion, and `ToHashSet()`.

Both of these calls will cause your enumerable to be evaluated, and thus call your construction of `TestNewGuid`

Answer (score 2):

`IEnumerable` uses lazy evaluation - elements are only evaluated when consumed.

In your example it means the Request Id is generated twice (at each point of consumption):

1. When `ToHashSet()` is called
2. When `First()` is referenced